# Subtract Display Pixels from Mouse Position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Full code can be viewed on JSBin - http://jsbin.com/inibAya/1/edit

So I'm working on a wysiwyg website designer and I added a crosshair to show the corrinates the mouse position is within the canvas. (NOTE: a div acts as the canvas not a html5 canvas element)

The div#canvas is positioned at...

```
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:44px; right:291px; bottom:16px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Whatever calculation I tried to remove the 44px from the canvas's display I got NaN or undefined. When the user moves their mouse I want it to start at 0 from the top left and move onwards. Does anyone know of anyway to get this to work?

Here's my JQuery/JavaScript:

```
// Crosshair
var cH = $('#crosshair-h'), cV = $('#crosshair-v');

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    cH.css('top', e.pageY);
    cV.css('left', e.pageX);
    $('#mousepos').text( "X: " + e.pageX + "px, Y: " + e.pageY + "px");
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? "Remove 44 pixels from..." something?

Comment: What is the "something" which you want to remove 44 pixels from? And what does that mean exactly? Do you want to decrease that something's width?

Comment: When I move my mouse across the div#canvas I have text display to show me where my cursor is within that div. In addition to a crosshair that is initiated when the doc is ready. I'm trying to subtract 44px on left for this move function even though the div#canvas css is set to be left:44px; | I made a small jsbin demo to show what I'm talking about - http://jsbin.com/inibAya/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `e.pageX`'s [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/):

> **Description:** The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document.

You will need to account for your canvas's offset (of 44px) to solve your problem.

```
var canvasPosition = $(canvas).position();

$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - canvasPosition.left;
  var y = e.pageY - canvasPosition.top;
  cH.css('top', e.pageY);
  cV.css('left', e.pageX);
  $('#mousepos').text( "X: " + x + "px, Y: " + y + "px");
});
```

[JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/inibAya/2/edit)